# AS2 error "There is no class or package with the name 'com.es3.ProgressBar'

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am using Flash CS5 and am getting a very odd error when I compile.  All my classes are in the package com.es3.as2.  In the first frame of my movie, I have the following code:

import com.es3.as2.Shell;

I have my classpath set correctly.  When I compile, I get this error:

> , Line 1  There is no class or package
>   with the name 'com.es3.ProgressBar'
>   found in package 'com.es3'.

This is odd because nowhere do I refer to a "com.es3" package. It's always "com.es3.as2".

If I remove the import line, the movie compiles with no errors (but without the initialization code, it doesn't run correctly).

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you have a broken import somewhere inside the imported package.

Answer (score 0):

What weltraumpirat said. :)  I have had this happen before.  You gotta search through the classes and see where its broken or replace the missing class if its not there.  One hackish way to fix it is to create a blank class by that name at the requested location.  Sometimes importing a whole package with * can result in unnecessary classes being imported.  If its not in use that approach shouldn't affect anything.  Not the classiest of solutions I know but as2 is a hack lol.